# xsd.exe does not create a collection (array or list) for xs:list tag

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have the following xsd tag which I expected to create a collection on deserialization but it doesn't.

```
<Metrics>
....
....
<xs:simpleType name="idType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value="99"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
...
...
<xs:element name="RPT">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list itemType="idType"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
...
...
</Metrics>
```

When I create the classes using command `xsd /c <xsd-filename>.xsd`, the RPT created is:

```
public partial class Metrics 
{
   ...
   ...
   private string rPTField;
   ...
   ...
}
```

I want `RPT` to be a collection type that returns the list elements.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Xsd.exe tends to treat nested types as strings, as they can get pretty complex, list of unions of restricted types etc... You may be in with a chance if you have a list of xs:int's.

```
<xs:element name="RPT">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:list itemType="xs:int"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Alternatively have a look at [Xml Objects online generator](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-to-cs-generator), it will generate code that looks like this from your XSD

**XSD**

```
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="idType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
            <xs:maxInclusive value="99" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="MyRootElement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="RPT">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:list itemType="idType" />
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Generated Code**

```
#region Elements
/// <summary>A class representing the root XSD element MyRootElement</summary>
/// <XsdPath>schema:schema.xsd/element:MyRootElement</XsdPath>
/// <XsdFile>file://sandbox/schema.xsd</XsdFile>
/// <XsdLocation>10:5-20:18</XsdLocation>
[LxSimpleElementDefinition("MyRootElement", "", ElementScopeType.GlobalElement)]
public partial class MyRootElementElm
{
    /// <summary>A <see cref="System.Int32" />[], Required : should not be set to null</summary>
    [LxElementValue("RPT", "", LxValueType.List, XsdType.XsdInt, MinOccurs = 1, MaxOccurs = 1)]
    public System.Int32[] RPT { get; set; } = new System.Int32[] {};

}
#endregion
```

It doesn't pick up the nested facet 0-99 but it gets the type right. Its also free for small XSD's.